Values outside table when making custom label for column in LaTex using pgfplotstable
In the FDR column of my table, I'm trying to set a custom label where 0 values are displayed as its integer representation, and any numbers with decimals are converted to scientific notation. I've managed to achieve the formatting I want in the image attached, but for some reason there are values floating outside my table and I get the following error. "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number format/.append int detect' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."My current table
I'm really not sure what the issue is, I have the pgfplots, pgfplotstable, and pgfkeys packages loaded. Here is my current code:
    \pgfplotstableset{
    % Define a custom display function for FDR column
    display FDR/.style={
        column name={FDR},
        assign cell content/.code={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                precision=1,
                sci,
                sci zerofill,
                precision=1,
                /pgf/number format/.append int detect,
            }%
            \pgfmathprintnumber{##1}\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd}%
        },
    },
}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\tiny
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns/Gene/.style = {string type},
    columns/RBP/.style = {string type},
    columns/FDR/.style = {display FDR},
    columns/LR/.style = {fixed relative, precision=3},
    every head row/.style = {
        before row=\hline,
        after row=\hline
    },
    every last row/.style = {after row=\hline},
        every column/.style={
        fixed relative, 
        precision=0, column type/.add={|}},
    every last column/.style={
        column type/.add={}{|}},
    every row no 9/.style={
        after row = \hline
    },
    every row no 19/.style={
        after row = \hline
    },
    every row no 29/.style={
        after row = \hline
    },
    every row no 39/.style={
        after row = \hline
    },
    every row no 49/.style={
        after row = \hline
    }
]{CsvFiles/exon_H_A3SS.csv}
\caption{Selected A3SS exons in HepG2 cell line}
\label{tab:Table A3SS exon}
\end{table}

